# How do I get a time difference estimate from right now in PHP. Similar to moment.js fromNow() function

Tags: php, time, momentjs

I normally use moment.js fromNow() to get a time difference estimate from the current time. (Will return things like a "a few seconds ago", "3 days ago", etc.)

I know that PHP's date_diff() function will return the exact time difference, but I need just an estimate of sorts.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to put a bit more initial effort, than just ask a plain “how do I do X” question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function get_time_ago($time)
{
    $time_difference = time() - strtotime($time);
    if( $time_difference < 1 ) { return 'less than 1 second ago'; }
    $condition = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 =>  'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
                60                      =>  'minute',
                1                       =>  'second'
    );

    foreach( $condition as $secs => $str )
    {
        $d = $time_difference / $secs;

        if( $d >= 1 )
        {
            $t = round( $d );
            return 'About ' . $t . ' ' . $str . ( $t > 1 ? 's' : '' ) . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```
echo get_time_ago('2019-11-22 15:22:35');
```